# Nodejs Sequelize Many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to fetch data from DB with sequelize. The many to many relationships between users and roles. When i fetch the users does not include the roles.

The code look like:

user model

```js
// model defines the user objects
const userModel = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const users = sequelize.define("user", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    firstname: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    lastname: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    image: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  });
  //don not show password and id
  users.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    let values = Object.assign({}, this.get());

    delete values.password;
    delete values.id;
    return values;
  };
  return users;
};
export default userModel;
```

Roles model

```js
// model defines the events objects
const rolesModel = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const roles = sequelize.define("roles", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    description: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  });
  return roles;
};
export default rolesModel;
```

The associations:

```js
db.users.associate = (db) => {
  db.users.belongsToMany(db.roles, {
    through: "userroles",
    constraints: false,
    foreignKey: "rolesId",
  });
};

db.roles.associate = (db) => {
  db.roles.belongsToMany(db.users, {
    through: "userroles",
    constraints: false,
    foreignKey: "userId",
  });
};
```

There are two controller functions that are adding and fetching the user data

Controller

```js
 User.create(userDetails)
      .then(() => {
        let roles = req.body.roles;
        roles.forEach(async (element) => {
          let role = await Roles.findByPk(element);
          if (role) {
            await Userroles.create({
              id: uniqid(),
              rolesId: element,
              userId: userId,
            });
          } else {
            logger.warn(`tried adding to ${userId} a none existent role`);
          }
        });
      })
      
      
      
// get user

 let user = await User.findOne({
      where: { email: username },
      include: { model: db.roles },
    });
```

So the roles are only a empty array when I try getting user details:
"firstname": "Mathew",
"lastname": "Murimi",
"email": "******@gmail.com",
"image": null,
"createdAt": "2022-02-12T22:56:40.000Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-02-12T22:56:40.000Z",
"roles": []

Comment: I suppose you need to change `let values = Object.assign({}, this.get());
` to `let values = Object.assign({}, this.get({ plain: true }));`

Comment: these ones are meant to hide password and Id of user from being fetched from db

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Receive the user created in the then, add the id of "newUser" in "userId"

```
User.create(userDetails)
  .then((**newUser**) => {
    let roles = req.body.roles;
    roles.forEach(async (element) => {
      let role = await Roles.findByPk(element);
      if (role) {
        await Userroles.create({
          id: uniqid(),
          rolesId: element,
          userId: **newUser.id**,
        });
      } else {
        logger.warn(`tried adding to ${**newUser.id**} a none existent role`);
      }
    });
  })
```